# Finding the $x$ and $y$ part of the side of the triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I need help finding x and y in this triangle. 
Conditions:
It is not a right triangle;
there are no given angles;
$u$ doesn't bisect the corresponding angle;
$u$ doesn't split $c$ in two equal parts;
$c,b,a$ and $u$ are given;
[Triangle example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcQ1Z.png)

[image]

Comment: Lookup [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem#Theorem).

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check someone did suggest Stewart's Theorem as a comment!

$xb^2 + yc^2 = (x+y)(u^2+xy)=au^2+axy$

From here, $x$ can be found out this way:
\begin{align}
& x(b^2-ay)+yc^2=au^2 \\
& \implies x(b^2-ay-c^2)=a(u^2-c^2) \\
& \implies \boxed{x = \frac{a(u^2-c^2)}{b^2-ay-c^2}}
\end{align}

Similarly, $$\boxed{y=a-x =a- \frac{a(u^2-c^2)}{b^2-ay-c^2}}$$

Comment: P.S : I know that the doubt's been resolved, yet to increase my points (I'm a new user), I just answered it.

Comment: Your expression for $x$ and $y$ should not have $x$ or $y$ because $x$ and $y$ are not given.

Comment: Yes, $y+x=a$, just replace this and the terms can be removed.

Comment: After we replace $y$ with $a-x$ in the expression of $x$, then we still need to solve for $x$.

Comment: @Delong that can be done by the OP.